# VS2017 Outlook Add-In, Modify Contact Page

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook Add-In that works with the user's contacts. I'm able to add a Form Region that will display a separate box below the contact details. But I'm wondering if it's possible to add controls that integrate into the contact details rather than a separate region below, like this:

[image]

I'm new to VS2017 and building Outlook Add-Ins, so maybe there's an obvious solution. But I haven't had any luck Googling for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that unless you replace the whole form.